# Terminal non responsive after installing XAMPP in virtual machine and using sudo

Tags: command-line, xampp

I have just installed Ubuntu 11 on virtual machine running on a windows seven,
I just downloaded the **xampp** package and wanted to install it, so I Googled how to install **xampp**, and it says I should login as a root user.

So I typed **sudo -s**, and the it asked for a password, but suddenly I cant type nothing, even that the mouse works?

Is that a common problem, does some know what it might be?
I looked on Google could not find a similar problem?

I am following this instruction for the installation of xampp. 
http://freshtutorial.com/install-xamp-ubuntu/

Comment: Is there any reason why you download software and not use ubuntu software center? there is a LAMP install that is tweaked for Ubuntu in USC. No need for 3rd party software.

Comment: @Rinzwind hey thanx for the feedback. I could not find a lamp on the software center.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install tasksel` and then type `tasksel` on commandline. Choose the `lamp` option ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind it sayz `tasksel: dbconf failed to run`. I chose the lamp server by just taking the cursor with the arrow key at the lamp server name. maybe other is some other way to chose my selection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your original question, 'suddenly I cant type nothing'.

Linux Command Line does this whenever a password is needed to be entered.

You are indeed entering a password, it just doesnt display what you type (even as asterisks) to aid security for that password.

Comment: It took me some time but I figured that out in the end. Thanx though :)